# Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs

Tags: set-theory

Among several possible definitions of ordered pairs - see below - I find Kuratowski's the least compelling: its membership graph (2) has one node more than necessary (compared to (1)), it is not as "symmetric" as possible (compared to (3) and (4)), and it is not as "intuitive" as (4) - which captures the intuition, that an ordered pair has a first and a second element.

[image][(source)](http://epublius.de/mathoverflow/orderedpairs.png)

<sup>*Membership graphs for possible definitions of ordered pairs (≙ top node, arrow heads omitted)*</sup>

```
1: (x,y) := {   x   , {   x   ,   y } }
2: (x,y) := { { x } , {   x   ,   y } } (Kuratowski's definition)
3: (x,y) := { { x } , { { x } ,   y } }
4: (x,y) := { { x , 0 }  ,  { 1 , y } } (Hausdorff's definition)
```

So my question is:

> Are there good reasons to choose
>   Kuratowski's definition (or did
>   Kuratowski himself give any) instead of
>   one of the more "elegant" - sparing,
>   symmetric, or intuitive -
>   alternatives?

Comment: My hypothesis would be that in case of non-Kuratowski definitions one would have some more technical dificulties in development of ordinal arithmetic in ZFC.

Comment: What is 1 in 4.?

Comment: @unknown (google): I think the idea in option 4 is that the constants 0 and 1 are fixed and chosen ahead of time --- certainly it doesn't matter up to isomorphism what they are, so set them to be some physical objects, if you like. 

Comment: An obvious remark: the aim of these definitions is not to capture the *essence* of "ordered pair", but just to bring this notion into the language of set theory (in the same spirit of von Neumann's definition of ordinal numbers, for instance). So it really doesn't matter which one we choose.  

Comment: Sorry: 0 is {}, and 1 is {0} = {{}}.

Comment: @HansStricker - what is the name of the notation you used for the membership graphs?

Comment: @smartcaveman: What do you mean? Which notation do you mean?

Comment: @HansStricker - the diagrams in the png file

Comment: Could it be this? In Kuratowski's definition there is a simple description of what the first and second elements of a pair $z$. The first element of $z$ is the unique member of $\bigcap z$. The second element of $z$ is the unique member of $\bigcup z$ if that has only one member and otherwise the unique member of $\bigcup z\backslash \bigcap z$.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Kuratowski's definition arose naturally out of Kuratowski's idea for representing any linear order of a set $S$ in terms of just sets, not ordered pairs.  The idea was that a linear ordering of $S$ can be represented by the set of initial segments of $S$.  Here "initial segment" means a nonempty subset of $S$ closed under predecessors in the ordering.  When applied to the special case of two-element sets $S$, this gives the Kuratowski ordered pair.

Answer (score 24):

Of course there are many pairing functions, and they all
have the crucial property that from the pair $(x,y)$, one
can reconstruct both $x$ and $y$. And although your
question has been answered, let me point out that all four
of the ordered pair definitions that you consider have the
property that the von Neumann rank of the pair $(x,y)$ is
strictly greater than the ranks of $x$ and $y$. Thus, for
your functions, if $x$ and $y$ are in $V_\alpha$, then the
pair $(x,y)$ can only be guaranteed to appear by
$V_{\alpha+2}$.

But actually, this rank-increasing feature is sometimes
annoying, and there occasionally arises in set-theoretic
argument the need or desire for a *flat* pairing function,
a pairing function that does not increase rank in this way.
Specifically, what is desired is a pairing function
$\langle x,y\rangle$ such that whenever $x,y\in V_\alpha$
for infinite $\alpha$, then also $\langle x,y\rangle\in
V_\alpha$, for the same rank $\alpha$. (Note that one
cannot achieve this for finite $\alpha\gt 1$, since there
are too many pairs to fit.) With such a flat pairing
function, every infinite $V_\alpha$ is closed under
pairing, and this is sometimes important or at least
convenient in inductive arguments, or in arguments about
$\alpha$-strong cardinals and in similar situations, where
one wants to consider only sets of a given rank, but one
also wants to use pairs.

It is a fun exercise to prove that flat pairing functions
exist, and I encourage you to try it on your own, before
reading what I write below. But the definitions are all
somewhat more involved than the comparatively simple
definitions you provide, since they achieve the flatness
property. As Hurkyl says, we ultimately care only about the
existence of the function with the desired properties,
rather than its exact nature.

Here is one way to construct a flat pairing function.
Define $\langle x,y\rangle=x^0\cup y^1$, where $x^0$ is
obtained by replacing every natural number $n$ in any
element of $x$ by $n+1$ and adding the object $0$, whereas
$y^1$ just replaces $n$ inside elements of $y$ with $n+1$.
Thus, we can tell from any element of $x^0\cup y^1$ whether
it came from $x$ or $y$, by looking to see if it contains
$0$ or not, and we can reconstruct the unmodified set by
removing $0$ and replacing all $n+1$ with $n$ again, and so
it is a pairing function. And one can check that $\langle
x,y\rangle$ has the same rank as the maximum rank of $x$
and $y$, if this max is infinite, and so this is a flat
pairing function, as desired.

Comment: Flat pairing functions are particularly important in type theory. For example we can regard every set of natural numbers as a code for a pair of sets, without leaving second-order arithmetic. Similarly every set of sets of natural numbers can be viewed as a code for a pair of sets of sets, without leaving third order arithmetic. I have heard flat pairing functions are also useful for non-ZF set theories such as New Foundations, although I don't know much about that area. 

Comment: This "flat" pairing function described above is what some people know as "Quine's definition" of an ordered pair. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine-Rosser_definition
As far as I know, this is the definition used by people working in NF and similar theories, it has the advantage that every set is an ordered pair and so the functions first(-) and second(-) (projections) are total functions instead of partial ones.

Answer (score 20):

How one models ordered pairs is not particularly important; what matters is the existence of a pairing function $(-,-)$ along with functions $\text{first}(-)$ and $\text{second}(-)$ satisfying the requisite properties.

Which definition you use only matters for a brief period between the definition and the point where its properties have been proven, at which point you promptly forget the details of the definition -- so the only real point of deliberating definitions is to make this period as painless as possible for others.

I haven't thought through all of the possibilities, but I will offer an example that $\text{first}(-)$ is tricky to define for your definition 1. The 'obvious' choice seems to be
$$ z = \text{first}(P) \equiv z \in P \wedge \exists a: z \in a \in P $$
which turns out to depend on the axiom of foundation to be well-defined! (consider a $y$ satisfying $y = \{ x, y \}$)
I, personally, would have more confidence in being correct if I was trying to develop the properties of ordered pairs from definitions 2 or 4, rather than from 1 or 3.

Comment: I think this answer basically hits the mark.  To the OP: It's the 21st century, so why do you care how to define ordered pairs in some set theory, when there are better languages available for doing mathematics?

Comment: Actually, definition 1 itself depends on the axiom of foundation to be a good model of ordered pairs. If x satisfies x={{x,y}, z}, then by definition 1:

({x,y}, z) = { {x,y}, { {x,y}, z } } = { {x,y}, x } = (x, y)

Comment: @Hurkyl: I was trying to work out that example, and you got there first!

Comment: So the point is from 2 you can recover the pair via the algorithm: $(x,y)$ has exactly one element that itself has precisely one element; this element is $\operatorname{first}(x,y)$.  If $(x,y)$ has more than one element, then it has precisely one element with precisely two elements; the element thereof that is not $\operatorname{first}(x,y)$ is $\operatorname{second}(x,y)$.  In 4, you use a similar algorithm: For $\operatorname{first}$, $(x,y)$ has an element that contains $0$, and at most one other element; if $\{0\} \in (x,y)$, return $0$; else return the other element in the (continued)

Comment: element of $(x,y)$ that contains $0$.  For option 3, again, you say: if your pair contains a unique element $a$, then $a = \{x\} = \{\{x\}\}$, so $x = \{x\}$ and return $\operatorname{first} = \operatorname{second} = a$; otherwise, the pair contains precisely two elements, (at least) one of which is a singleton; if precisely one is a singleton, you know what to do, but if both are singletons and different, you have to think.  You're OK if in your foundations, the equations $a = \{b\}$ and $b = \{a\}$ together imply $a=b$, and not otherwise.

Comment: Theo, regarding your first comment, is it your view that it isn't necessary to define an ordered pair concept in set theory? Or are you saying that it isn't necessary or desirable to do set theory at all?

Comment: @Joel, I think he's saying that the concept of ordered pair, as well as every other concept in mathematics, is better interpreted in some language/theory other than the language of sets/ZFC.

Comment: @Theo, one appeal of set theory as a foundations is that while it's simple in the sense that it only takes membership as primitive, thus allowing for a cleaner analysis of the foundations, it's expressive power is such that it can interpret most of mathematics, thus for the mathematician who wants to take "ordered pair" as a primitive notion, he or she can do so without raising new foundational questions.  Are you suggesting a language that doesn't take membership as primitive?  If so, how would you address concerns that membership ought to be a primitive notion? (continued)

Comment: Or are you suggesting a language that takes additional things as primitive?  If so, is the payoff in additional expressive power enough to make up for the loss of simplicity? Maybe these questions are too broad for a comment thread, but what the heck.

Comment: @Hurkyl: What exactly is a function in your setting? Do you mean a formula, an "algorithm", or a set (of ordered tuples)? Or is there no difference?

Comment: One formulation of what I mean is as a *class* of ordered tuples (satisfying the property that makes it a function), where a *class* is (as usual) defined by a logical predicate.