# What kind of algebra is the class of ordered pairs equipped with the binary operation which forms them?

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra

There are many definitions of ordered pair in set theory, but all such definitions have the *characteristic property of ordered pair:*

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x, y) = (x', y') \leftrightarrow \ (x = x' \ and \ y = y')\ \ \ \ $(*)

The comma in the expression "$(x, y)$" can be treated as a binary operation over sets resulting in an ordered pair. My question is about this operation. The term "$(x, y)$" can be an operation symbol of the language of a set theory T, and my question is easier to be answered for this case, than for the case when this operation is defined by a concrete definition (Kuratowski's, Wiener's, etc.). Thus, what kind of algebra is "$(U, \ (x, y))$", where U denotes the universe of discourse of a set theory T, and "$(x, y)$" is an operation symbol in the language of T?

To make the question correct, I would have to use such terms as "class-algebra", say that $U$ is a Grothendieck universe, or otherwise take care of foundations. But the question is about **algebraic properties** of this algebra and to keep focus on this, I would keep the aspect of "size" ("set" versus "class") fuzzy for now.

The property (*) is neither an identity, nor a quasi-identity - do algebraists handle such properties of a binary operation?

Here is one reason why this question is interesting. Set theory can be presented algebraically, but then it would be nice that the formulas of such an algebraic set theory are treated on same basis as their interpretations ("within the same universe of discourse"). A formula can be treated as result of multiple applications of the operation $(x, y)$ and, therefore, it would be nice to get an idea of the algebraic properties of this operation - whence my question.

I guess, the AST (Algebraic Set Theory) presented in the language ofcategory theory treats syntax on the same basis as semantics. But can my question be answered in the language of universal algebra?

Comment: I don't understand. Part of the point of the formation of ordered pairs is that it should satisfy no algebraic identities whatsoever.

Comment: But maybe there are other properties, different from identities, of such algebras - properties, which can be expressed in terms of homomorphisms, direct products, subalgebras, etc. I am interested in any study of algebras with such a binary operation satisfying the property (*).

Comment: If you are happy with a set sized universe, there are algebras with decomposition operation that are used to study cartesian products of algebras.  Do a web search for details.  One of the operations behaves something like (a,b)*(c,d) yields (a,d).

Comment: @JamesCranch Your objection applies when one considers the ordered pair $(x,y)$ to have a different type than $x$ or $y$, but here we mix them together in one algebra $U$, and so obviously there will be some instances that have additional structure, as I explain in my answer. For example, some ordered-pair concepts have $U\times U=U$, and others have $U\times U\subsetneq U$.

Comment: @Masked Avenger, the algebras you referred to sound interesting, especially due to the "*" operation. I searched the web, but I could not find anything mentioning this operation. Can you please give me a key word or expression for web search?

Comment: I've only just seen this question. Can't your condition (*) be treated simply as a pair of quasi-identities over the signature with one binary operation $f$, namely $f(x, y) = f(x', y') \to x = x'$ and $f(x, y) = f(x', y') \to y = y'$? In any event, the category of such algebras would form a locally finitely presentable category. I can't recall seeing this example in the literature though.

Comment: @IoachimDrugus, I apologize for the late reply.  (I don't know how I missed your reply.)  Algebras, Lattices, Varieties Vol. 1 by McKenzie, McNulty, and Taylor has a section in Chapter 4 on decomposition operations.  If you haven't encountered this yet, I recommend it to you.

Comment: @Todd, you might check out  Bjorn's answer.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger Ah yes, there it is. Thanks. Might you have missed Ioachim's reply because he didn't write "The" Masked Avenger? (I'll probably never understand why you use this handle.)

Comment: It's possible I was not notified.  I usually check back though, so I am still puzzled.   I find this handle convenient in "being" someone else, and find it useful in the practice of changing perspective.  I also found it useful in seeing differences in behaviour when interacting with other members.  Of course, always with the intent and practice of supporting and not abusing the platform.

Comment: I found Algebras, Lattices, Varieties Volumes 1 and 2. Looks like a great book. Now I am looking into this. Thank you.

Comment: @Ioachim, Volume 2 is out? Tell me more!  I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded "Volume II" from here: http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/alv10.pdf

Comment: I have seen that.  That is one chapter out of Volume II, which has between 6 and 9 chapters.  As far as I know, the actual volume II is still being rewritten.  Gerhard "Has Old Volume Two Draft" Paseman, 2015.03.27

Answer (score 9):

The property (*) is actually equivalent to a set of quasi-identities:
$$(x,y)=(x',y')\rightarrow x=x'$$
$$(x,y)=(x',y')\rightarrow y=y'$$
The converse implication you had ($\leftarrow$) is logically valid and hence does not need to be mentioned.

Comment: And therefore the class of sets equipped with a binary operation which satisfies these conditions is stable under isomorphisms, subalgebras, and products.

Comment: It is nice to hear that (*) reduces to quasiidentities. So, these algebras form a quasivariety. This reduction is done via the two projections. Interesting, if we add symbols for projections to the signature of this algebra  would the theory of new algebras be essentially the same? It seems I sure ask this manner - "would the theory of new algebras be a conservative extension?"

Comment: It depends on how you arrange things.  The Jonsson-Tarski algebras mentioned in another answer have a nice equational setup:  l(p(x,y))=x=r(p(y,x))= p(l(x),r(x)).  This gives trivial or infinite algebras, and is a nice example to use in studying algebras with pairing and projection functions.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2014.07.13

Answer (score 6):

Since your algebra mixes together the objects $x$ and $y$ with
their pair $(x,y)$ in the same algebra, it has the effect of
erasing "ordered-pair" as a separate type in this context, and so there is no
reason to expect that condition $(*)$ is all the structure one
will expect to find. For example, in your algebra you can form
iterated terms like $(x,(y,z))$ and inquire whether $x=(x,y)$ is
possible, while in a more highly typed context, such an equation
wouldn't even be sensible necessarily. For this reason, there are numerous pairing functions that exhibit all kinds of other extra algebraic structure in the algebra you
are considering.

For example, many of the usual ordered-pair definitions in set
theory have the property that $(x,y)$ has higher rank than $x$ and
$y$, and in particular, $x\neq (x,y)\neq y$.

Similarly, for most of the pairing functions, $\emptyset\neq (x,y)$, and so
these pairing function are never a bijection of $U\times U$ with $U$.

But there are other pairing functions that do constitute a bijection between $U\times U$ and $U$, and in this sense it would be correct to write $U\times U=U$. This would include some of the usual
[flat
pairing functions](https://mathoverflow.net/a/62801/1946)
one sees in set theory, where actually every set $x$ is $(y,z)$
for some $y$ and $z$, and so the pairing function is a bijection
of $U\times U$ with $U$. Indeed, with the flat pairing functions I
have in mind, $V_\theta\times V_\theta=V_\theta$ for any infinite
ordinal $\theta$, and this includes all the Grothendieck universes
you were considering.

One can easily design artificial pairing functions that have other
extra properties, such as having fixed-point objects $x$ for which
$x=(x,x)$ and hence $x=(x,(x,x))=(((x,x),x),x)$ and so on, or
having no such fixed-points $x$. One could also make pairing
functions that had various instances of finite cycles $x=(x,y)$,
$y=(y,z)$ and $z=(z,x)$ and so on. One can easily arrange crazy
stuff, since of course the only requirement that $(*)$ imposes is
that $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is injective.

If $(x,y)$ is a pairing function and $\pi:U\to U$ is any injective function, then $(x,y)_\pi:=\pi((x,y))$ is another pariing function. And indeed, all pairing functions arise this way from any given surjective pairing function.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there an ordered-pair definition which does not raise the rank?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what "flat" means for the flat pairing functions. They don't raise ranks on any infinite set. Another way to say this is that every $V_\theta$ for infinite $\theta$ is closed under pairs. (It is impossible to never increase rank, since the finite ranks $V_k$ cannot be closed under pairing (for $k>1$) on finite cardinality grounds, since $n^2$ is larger than $n$ for $n>1$.

Comment: From your answer, it sound correct to name the algebras which I described, "pairing algebras".

Comment: Thus, an ordered pair can be defined in such a manner that it encrypts not only order but also some additional information. This is very interesting because (1) this justifies using pairing algebras in encoding formulas as sets as I described their intended use in my question (2) Some properties of sets can be expressed in the language of pairing algebra and equality, which is useful for an algebraic set theory.

Comment: I would go along with that.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure but I believe up to isomorphism this kind of structure is indistinguishable from arbitrary embedding $A\times A\hookrightarrow A$.

Sort of related are the s. c. [Jónsson-Tarski algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/J%C3%B3nsson-Tarski+algebra) --- when one requires that the above is actually a bijection. The latter are equational in the well known way, and play important rôles in various fields, being source of many interesting counterexamples.

Comment: Jónsson-Tarski algebras seem to be a sub-class of pairing algebras - "well-behaved pairing algebras".

Answer (score 2):

Universal algebra prefers to use a language in which the class of algebras under investigation is equationally defined (in other words: is a variety).  This is why groups are often not written as structures $(G,*)$ but rather as structures $(G,*, 1, {}^{-1})$. (Or, rarely, as structures $(G,/)$, where $x/y:= x*y^{-1}$.)

I think the situation is similar here.  If you do not require the pairing function to be onto, then the (in my opinion) natural way to represent your structures as algebras is to equip them with unary functions $l$ and $r$, and require $l(x*y)=x$, $r(x*y)=y$.    (I use $*$ rather than the comma as the pairing operation.)

This makes your family of "sets with a pairing function" into an equationally defined class.

Every algebra $(A,*)$ with a pairing function in your sense can be expanded to an 
algebra $(A,*,l,r)$ in my sense.  This implies that the first order theory of "my" algebras (the consequences of the two laws I gave) is a conservative extension of the theory of "your" algebras. (However, I think that this theory is quite trivial.)

An even more natural way would be to declare $l$ and $r$ to be partial functions, but it seems to me that partial functions are not popular in universal algebra.

Of course, if you do require the pairing function to be onto, you have to add the axiom $l(z)*r(z) = z$, and get a Jónsson-Tarski algebra, as remarked in previous answers.

Comment: Maybe, my question should have sounded like this: Can the ordered pair concept serve as foundation of (finitary) mathematics, and if it can, then can this foundation be algebraic? In such presentation, I would not regard the algebra above, with or without projections, as a "trivial algebra". It might be "trivial" only same manner as the free algebras are "trivial". It would be great to hear comments on this more general question from @Joel and others who gave here so useful answers, once I probably cannot ask again my question in a more general form.