# Why can't $L_\beta$ contain a real coding a well-ordering of order-type $\beta$, when $\beta$ is a gap ordinal?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, inner-model-theory, constructibility, inner-models

In [*Gaps in the constructible universe, Marek and Srebrny, 1973*](https://zbmath.org/?q=Gaps%20in%20the%20constructible%20universe%2C%20Marek%20and%20Srebrny) a gap ordinal is defined as follows

> $\alpha$ is a gap ordinal iff $(L_{\alpha+1}-L_\alpha)\cap \mathcal{P}(\omega) = \emptyset$

Their Lemma 2.4. and its proof are

> Let $\alpha$ be a gap ordinal. If $X \in \mathcal{P}(\omega) \cap L_\alpha$ and $X$ is a real well-ordering, then the type of $X$ is less than $\alpha$.
>
> **Proof.** Assume not. We can construct a tree coding all of $L_\alpha$ within $L_\alpha\cap \mathcal{P}(\omega)$. Now, we apply Cantor's diagonal procedure to obtain a new set of natural numbers.

As usual, by $X$ being a real well-ordering they mean $X = \{ J(m, n) \: | \: \langle m, n \rangle \in R \}$, where $R$ is a well-ordering of the naturals and $J$ a fixed pairing bijection. $X$ is order-isomorphic to $R$.

I'm familiar with Cantor's diagonal procedure, but I don't understand what they mean by a tree coding $L_\alpha$ within $L_\alpha\cap \mathcal{P}(\omega)$, neither know how to make sure it is definable over $L_\alpha$, or how to diagonalize from that.

Comment: The mention of "tree" here presumably refers to the details of how the authors code countable transitive sets as reals (earlier in the paper, I hope). But those details shouldn't matter here. Any reasonable coding of $L_\alpha$ by a real will provide an enumeration of the reals of $L_\alpha$ in an $\omega$-sequence. Diagonalization provides a new real definable from that enumeration, and one then needs to check that this definition can be carried out over $L_\alpha$ and so produces a member of $L_{\alpha+1\}$.

Comment: A "tree coding $L_\alpha$" is a structure $(\mathbb N,\prec)$ that's isomorphic to $(L_\alpha,\in)$. In fact, the Mostowski collapse of $(\mathbb N,\prec)$ is $(L_\alpha,\in)$, and Marek calls the Mostowski collapse of a well-founded tree the realization of that tree. More information here: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm82/fm82112.pdf#page=2

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for your answer, I now understand their argument, but I still can't see how this real coding all of $L_\alpha$ can be defined over $L_\alpha$ using $X$ (especially since $L_\alpha$ doesn't necessarily satisfy any nice theory, since it might be a successor level).

Comment: @MartínS Actually, (infinite) successor levels of $L$ aren't too bad: using a [constructible flat pairing function](https://mathoverflow.net/a/62801/8133), we can do all the same basic combinatorial constructions albeit in a messier way. (I think Devlin has some details on this.) However, in this particular case you don't even have to go that far - you can directly show that the successor of a non-gap ordinal is a non-gap ordinal, and this lets you reduce the successor case to the limit case.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your answer. Exactly, but the last condition you mention is equivalent to showing any start of a gap is a limit, and that seems pretty nontrivial. I've got a proof of it through some Lemmas, but I can't see a direct way to prove it quickly.